# My scrapy project doesnt store the data in a file

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I just started working with scrapy.
I am tying to my anime list top 50 anime and do something with it.

My spider contains the following code:

```
import scrapy 


class AnimeSpider(scrapy.Spider):   
    name="animelist"
    start_urls=[
        'https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php'
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        for anime in response.css('tr.rankinglist'):
            yield {
                'name':anime.css("div.di-ib clearfix >a::text").extract_first(), 
                'score':anime.css(".js-top-ranking-score-col di-ib al > span.text::text").extract_first(),           
        }

        next_page=response.css('a.link-blue-box     next::attr("href")').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

When I run my code all these things happen:

```
berseker@berseker-Inspiron-15-3567:~/python$ scrapy runspider         anime_spider.py -o anime.json
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) - [GCC 7.2.0], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Linux-4.15.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': 'anime.json', 'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
         'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item     pipelines:
[]
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-11-09 12:02:20 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-11-09 12:02:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php> (referer: None)
2018-11-09 12:02:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-11-09 12:02:23 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy     stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 226,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 16558,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 9, 6, 32, 23, 224266),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 53026816,
 'memusage/startup': 53026816,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 9, 6, 32, 20, 685482)}
2018-11-09 12:02:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed     (finished)
```

After all this my file anime.json stays empty. Why does this happen and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to test whether your selector is working fine or not, you should run `scrapy shell "https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php"` in the terminal/cmd and then running the selectors like `response.css('tr.rankinglist')` will show you the output that you will get. and there you can fine tune your selectors accordingly

Answer (score 1):

your selector

```
response.css('tr.rankinglist')
```

is wrong, it returns empty list so you don't have any items.
Class is `ranking-list`. Selector should be

```
response.css('tr.ranking-list')
```

or

```
response.xpath("//tr[@class='ranking-list'])
```

Comment: thanks, it worked I really need to fresh up my css before this.